# Issues with session write/read since changing from server sessions to redis sessions

Tags: php, session, amazon-ec2, redis

Our PHP application is showing some strange behaviour since we made the switch from regular server sessions to sessions stored in Redis.

The PHP code hasn't changed, but we notice an issue when writing a session variable which is read in the same function chain.

I'll try to give an example of the code with pseudo code:

```
  //some code
...
  session_start();
  //now we write the session variable
  $_SESSION[key] = value;
  session_close();
...
  //some other code
  
  return getSomeSpecificValue();
}

function getSomeSpecificValue(){
  //some code
  ...
  session_start();
  $someVar = $_SESSION[key];
  session_close();
  ...
  //some code
  
}
```

Now the problem is that, since moving to redis sessions, it happens that the variable is empty when reading it, even though we have just written it.

That behaviour did not occur before the move to Redis. Is there a specific race condition or setting we are missing? Or do we need to change the code now?

If anyone can help us out with pointers on where to look, that would be much appreciated. If you need more info, let me know, we have been debugging this issue but can't seem to find a solution for it. Race condition? Data lock? ..

When refreshing the page, the value is not empty anymore, so we are pretty sure it's written to redis, probably on the first attempt (?) :-).

Comment: It could be a race condition, that the session hasn't had time to write it before you open and try and read it again. You could either test to only start it once per request and don't call close at all (and only change that back if you notice any issues with it). Otherwise you can test changing `session_close()` to `session_write_close()` and see if that makes any difference. Just remember that any `session_start()` _must_ be called before any kind of output at all.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `Redis Extension on the Web Server` e.g for `php5`

```
sudo apt-get install php5-redis
```

Then add the session handler in web server e.g

On LAMP environments:

```
sudo vim /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

On LEMP environments:

```
sudo vim /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

Add This lines

```
[label /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini] 
session.save_handler = redis
```

Then restart web server.

I didn't test the solution but should work. I compiled this answer from this articles https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-redis-server-as-a-session-handler-for-php-on-ubuntu-14-04, https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-redis-as-session-handler-php/ & https://bestofphp.com/repo/1ma-RedisSessionHandler-php-miscellaneous.

Comment: As I understood their question, they have already moved to redis for sessions (which means that they should already have done the above) and are now asking about a specific issue; The session data they store can't be read later in the same script, before a page reload.

Comment: @M.Eriksson that is correct, we are wondering why the session data can not be read immediately after it was set. That works with server sessions, not with redis sessions for us.